# PG Bouncer is not able to handle 1000 concurrent requests

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, pgbouncer

I am using PostgreSQL along with the PGBouncer. But PGBouncer is not able to handle even the 1000 concurrent requests.

Am I missing any configuration because of which it is happening?
Has anyone faced the similar situation? 
Is there any way to handle such situation with the same setup? 
Is there any other better alternative which has a quick replacement for PGBouncer(possible to be done in an hour or so)?

Comment: Why do you think it cannot handle 1000 concurrent connections? What error are you seeing? How have you configured it? What sort of machine is in running on? Nobody can help if you keep all the details secret.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point but hardware wise we are all good the only issue we are facing it because of it's single threading. It's not handling 1000 concurrent requests. It's happening with us.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413962/how-to-increase-the-connection-throughput-for-pgbouncer